# Setting default ignore_above value for dynamically mapped keywords

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm using the .NET OpenSearch client to dynamically map objects. The keyword fields' ignore_above attribute are all set to 256 characters. Documentation here states that is the expected value for default dynamic mapping: https://opensearch.org/docs/1.3/opensearch/supported-field-types/keyword/

The language "default dynamic mapping" makes me think this is a configurable option for dynamic mapping. Does anyone know how that could be done?

To be clear, I'm looking for a solution that would set all keyword fields to a specified value, not manually setting an individual keyword field.